# Easy way to check for a valid solution in this triple equality?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, number-theory

Let's say I have the following equalities

$a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + a_3x_3 + a_4x_4 = b_1x_1 + b_2x_2 + b_3x_3 + b_4x_4 = c_1x_1 + c_2x_2 + c_3x_3 + c_4x_4$

Where the $a$'s, $b$'s, and $c$'s are known, non-negative integers.

Is there an efficient way to check if a solution exists (the $x$'s) such that they are non-negative real numbers (except for the trivial case of all $x$'s being 0)? I don't need to actually calculate them, just need some way to see if a solution even exists.

Comment: There is always a solution: all $x_i = 0$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to clarify that. Editing OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After subtracting one of your expressions from the other two, you have two homogeneous linear equations, which you can write as 
$ A x = 0$, where $A$ is a $2 \times 4$ matrix.  By a theorem of Gordan (or the duality theory of linear programming) this has a solution with $x \ge 0$ and $x \ne 0$ if and only if
the system $A^T y < 0$ has no solution, i.e. there are no real $y_1, y_2$ with
all four entries of $A^T y < 0$.  By homogeneity it suffices to look at the three cases 
$y_1 = 1$, $y_1 = 1$ and $y_1 = -1$.  In each case, the four entries of $A^T y$ give us four inequalities on $y_2$, and it is easy to check if a solution exists.

EDIT: In your example, subtract the third expression from the other two to get
$$ \eqalign{x_1 - x_2 + x_3 &= 0\cr -x_1 \phantom{- x_2} + x_3 &= 0\cr}$$
The system $A^T y < 0$ says
$$ \eqalign{y_1 - y_2 &< 0 \cr
            -y_1 \phantom{-y_2} &< 0\cr
             y_1 + y_2 &< 0\cr}$$
The second row says $y_1 > 0$, so we take $y_1 = 1$, and then we need
$1 - y_2 < 0$, i.e. $y_2 > 1$, and $1 + y_2 < 0$, i.e. $y_2 < -1$.  These 
are contradictory, so we conclude that $A^T y < 0$ has no solution, and your 
system does have a nonnegative nonzero solution.

Comment: Would you be able to show a quick example of what you mean by this? Let's say I had the following (only 3 x's in this one): 

$2x_1+1x_2+2x_3 = 0x_1+2x_2+2x_3 = 1x_1+2x_2+1x_3$

Comment: How did you get from the system of equations with x to the system of equations with y's?

Comment: Each inequality for $y$'s corresponds to an $x$ variable, and each $y$ variable corresponds to an equation for the $x$'s.
The coefficients are the same.  Thus the coefficient of $x_2$ in the first equation $(-1)$ is the coefficient of $y_1$ in the second inequality.

Comment: If the $x$ equations were
$$\eqalign{x_1 + 2 x_2 + 3 x_3 &= 0\cr
          4 x_1 + 5 x_2 + 6 x_3 &= 0\cr}$$
then the $y$ inequalities would be
$$\eqalign{y_1 + 4 y_2 &< 0\cr
           2 y_1 + 5 y_2 &<0\cr
           3 y_1 + 6 y_2 &<0\cr}$$

Comment: Sorry to bother you again (if you would prefer I open up a new question I can do that), but can't you simplify things even further by subtracting the two x equations after you subtracted the third? For instance reducing it further to 2x1- x2 = 0?

Comment: You can, but you still need two equations, otherwise you lose some information.  So you can use equation 1 and equation 2, or you can use equation 1 and (equation 1 - equation 2), or ...